# Alternative to default argument in a protocol Swift

Tags: swift

I understand that a default argument is not permitted in a protocol, meaning that the following is not valid:

```
protocol testProtocol {
    func testFunc (_ a: String, _ b: String? = nil)
}
```

So I understand that b can still be optional by the following declaration

```
protocol testProtocol {
    func testFunc (_ a: String, _ b: String?)
}
```

and my class can conform to this protocol:

```
class TestIt: testProtocol {
    func testFunc(_ a: String, _ b: String?) {
        print ("Do stuff with a and b")
    }
}
```

However I would like to call this function with the following declaration:

```
let test = TestIt()

    test.testFunc("a")
```

Inevitably this does not compile, and the solution seems to be

```
let test = TestIt()
test.testFunc("a", nil)
```

However passing nil to a function does not seem a very swifty way of doing things.

Note that this is a minimum example, is not production ready and is simply to identify a solution to the general problem of passing nil in a protocol.

Can I call testFunc without using nil?

Comment: What is the general meaning of passing in nil to the second argument for this protocol?

Comment: This is a minimum example to show the problem space. There is no use to either a or b in this example, but assume I want to use them. The names test and testIT are also not production ready! I've updated the question to try to make this clearer.

Comment: I get that. But every hypothetical example comes from a real world problem. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do like this:

```swift
protocol TestProtocol {
    func testFunc (_ a: String, _ b: String?)
}

extension TestProtocol {
    func testFunc (_ a: String) {
        self.testFunc(a, nil)
    }
}
```